# bash: stty: command not found error in SSH

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to install applications from the Magento Repository via Bitvise SSH, but I'm getting the following error in all cases (this case is an attempt to install the Data Migration tool) right after it prompts me for a password (I have no opportunity to enter a password): bash: stty: command not found

```
datasolv@am17 [~/public_html/catalog]# composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: <public key>
      Password: bash: stty: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue. You can simply add a `auth.json` file in the same folder as your `composer.json`.

This will automatically authenticate you. You don't need to manually enter your credentials anymore, avoiding the `bash: stty: command not found`-error.

Content of `auth.json`:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<your public key>",
            "password": "<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

Save the file and run your command again.